# What is avg. optimal connection timeout for mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, timeout

This question is about trying to find a scientifically or statistically defensible rationale for choosing a timeout.  I mean every app must do this, but what is the optimal timeout? We need more people to answer or comment. +3, +4 does not mean the question is solved. An important question deserves more answers. We can all benefit from this knowledge.

Basically trying to compare:

```
   a short timeout of say 20 seconds, but two connection attempts are made
```

vs

```
   one long connection attempt of say 40 or 60 seconds.
```

Which has the best chance of establishing a connection? We need hard facts.  So far the numbers I am getting are all over the place 10s, 42, 60s.  But what is really optimal?

Now of course after 5-10 seconds the user should be informed of a problem either way, but whats the best effort approach for establishing a connection.

Note: I am aware that there are many factors, but as app developers we can't always get permission to examine wifi signal situation etc.  Still there must be some rational answer of what is best on average.

Comment: The answer is clearly 42. Or 60, that's what [AndroidHttpClient](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.java#AndroidHttpClient) uses as default.

Comment: But does it do retries for connection during this time?

Comment: Afaik no. The problem with mobile connections is that they will regularly drop for several seconds and if you have your timeouts too tight you may get nothing at all.

Comment: The question is what is tight? how do we quantify this?  How do we get the average number.

Comment: I don't know. You can test with thousands of devices in different mobile networks at different places and different target servers to find out :) I just keep the 60seconds and show that information is being loaded so the user knows something is happening. Or you show that no connection is possible but try silently. Timeout is not necessarily tied to the UI.

Comment: Ok. Well how about someone with an app that is deployed on thousands of devices in different mobile networks discussing what their findings are? Anyone out there with such an app?  Mine is such an app but we have not yet optimized it.

Comment: This is as much a UX question as it is a technical question - both aspects need to be taken into account. See my answer below for the UX aspect (borrowed from ux.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 9):

You will hopefully get better answers, but from personal experience I can talk about the user side of things. If I open an app that requires a data connection, such as my web browser or a social client, I want it to timeout in under 5 seconds, because it shouldn't take a long time to determine if I actually have a connection or not.

It is possible to look at it from a device standpoint, but that's highly variable (wifi vs. 3G, specific network chip, OS, data connection currently active, etc.) whereas user requirement are probably the most important factor. You could get away with like 30 seconds if the data connection isn't necessarily critical for the application, but the major point is that the technological limitation is only a part of how long you should budget for a connection timeout.

Comment: I think this offers insight into when the user should know about a potential connection failure.  I am also trying to determine what is the optimal approach to actually getting a connection within a window of say 60 seconds.  is it one long try or several shorter attempts.

Answer (score 6):

I always put ten seconds as a maximum, although **that is a personal preference**. Think about if you're holding your phone for five seconds and waiting for information to appear. I would already be frustrated - thus adding the double value seems appropriate. If there is a problem I would like to know about it via a `Toast`, footer view or something else.

Comment: I would agree that some information must appear to the user within 5-10 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what [the UX research says about user attention](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/56747/3587) (interesting parts are highlighted):

> - Longer than **1 second** breaks flow of thought
> - Longer than **10 seconds** loses the users attentions
> - Most simple tasks should be completed within **1 Minute**
>
> So if it is a task important to the user then 60 seconds delay is OK. Otherwise more than 10 seconds is an issue. **The peculiar thing is that the 20 to 50 seconds timeframe does not have great bearing on user impact -- it's all time after "attention lost" but before "will abandon a task".**
>
> Essentially if you can't go down to a 10 second time-out limit, then don't bother and tackle the UX issue a different way.

Obviously, this will not apply to every situation, so take it with a grain of salt.